# Create/bind and unbind/delete rabbitmq queue in Spring constantly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rabbitmq, amqp

I am now working on a project with rabbitmq, Spring, and Hibernate, where once my program is running, the user can change a boolean field in the database.

If true, my program will create a new queue and bind an predetermined exchange to it.

If false, my program will unbind the queue and delete it.

However, the tutorials I have seen all seem to use annotation to create the queue and the binding when the program first runs:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Profile({"tut3", "pub-sub", "publish-subscribe"})
@Configuration
public class Tut3Config {

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange fanout() {
        return new FanoutExchange("tut.fanout");
    }

    @Profile("receiver")
    private static class ReceiverConfig {

        @Bean
        public Queue autoDeleteQueue1() {
            return new AnonymousQueue();
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue autoDeleteQueue2() {
            return new AnonymousQueue();
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding binding1(FanoutExchange fanout,
            Queue autoDeleteQueue1) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(autoDeleteQueue1).to(fanout);
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding binding2(FanoutExchange fanout,
            Queue autoDeleteQueue2) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(autoDeleteQueue2).to(fanout);
        }

        @Bean
        public Tut3Receiver receiver() {
            return new Tut3Receiver();
        }
    }

    @Profile("sender")
    @Bean
    public Tut3Sender sender() {
        return new Tut3Sender();
    }
}
```

In my case, rather than using annotations, should I implement interfaces such as AmqpAdmin and use methods such as declareQueue() and deleteQueue explicitly to be able to create and delete queue constantly?

If that's the case, does Spring have a specific place in projects to implment those methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a single queue with filter-based message listeners?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the queues beans `autoDeleteQueue1` and `autoDeleteQueue1` are created with scope **singleton** and so they live within Spring container for a whole app lifecycle.

If you need more flexible way to handle queue beans, you can use the default implementation of AmqpAdmin, like it's described below.

```
if (condition) {
    Queue queue = admin.declareQueue(new Queue("queueOne"));
    admin.declareBinding(new Binding(queue, fanout))
} else {
    admin.removeBindings(new Binding(new Queue("queueOne"), fanout))
}
```

You may want to put this code into some Service or whatever the class which handles this logic. Within that service you may wire the beans

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin admin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange fanout() {
    return new FanoutExchange("tut.fanout");
}
```

More details can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#_very_very_quick)

Here's also [nice article with nice examples](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/04/amqp-messaging-with-rabbitmq/)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the tutorial for RabbitMQ using Java, you will find [#2](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) and [#5](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html) tutorial apply to your case.

For example, to create a queue you could use this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
```

To create binding, you can do this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();

if (argv.length < 1) {
  System.err.println("Usage: ReceiveLogsTopic [binding_key]...");
  System.exit(1);
}

for (String bindingKey : argv) {
  channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, bindingKey);
}
```

For your case, basically you want to explictly create the channel and create/bind explicitly rather than through beans.

Each of those operations can be its own method gathered in a service class.

Then you can simply utilize the service class for using each method.  This way you can create/bind anytime you want.